# Content of XML file is not display with .NET Web API 2 application

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, xml

I develop .NET Web API application. It must display list of users. The content of the list is loaded from XML file. But list of users isn't shown in application window and I don't know why. Below is the model:

```html
namespace UserDirectory.Models
{
    /// <summary>
    /// User class provides information about user.
    /// </summary>
    public class User
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Surname and initials.
        /// </summary>
        public String Name { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Login for authorization.
        /// </summary>
        public String Login { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Password for authorization.
        /// </summary>
        public String Password { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// User roles in work process (administrator, etc.)
        /// </summary>
        public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates an instance of User class.
        /// </summary>
        public User()
        {
            Roles = new List<Role>();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Role class provides information abiut user role.
    /// </summary>
    public class Role
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Name of the role.
        /// </summary>
        public String Name { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Is this role is assigned to user.
        /// If it is assigned then - true, otherwise - false.
        /// </summary>
        public Boolean Assigned { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the controller:

```html
public class UsersController : ApiController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the list of users.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>List of users</returns>
        public IEnumerable<User> Get()
        {
            // Users list representation.
            List<User> users = new List<User>();

            // Get "Users.xml" file content.
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "..\\..\\App_Data\\Users.xml");
            // Fill user list representation:
            foreach (XElement elemUser in doc.Descendants("Users").Descendants("User"))
            {
                // Create record about single user.
                User user = new User();
                // Get his surname and initials.
                user.Name = elemUser.Element("Name").Value;
                // Get his loginе.
                user.Login = elemUser.Element("Login").Value;
                // Get his password.
                user.Password = elemUser.Element("Password").Value;
                // Get all of his potential roles:
                foreach (XElement elemRole in elemUser.Descendants())
                {
                    // Create buffer for role information.
                    Role role = new Role();
                    // Get the name of role.
                    role.Name = elemRole.Attribute("name").Value;
                    // Has this role been assigned for user?
                    bool f_Assigned;
                    if (Boolean.TryParse(elemRole.Value, out f_Assigned))
                        role.Assigned = f_Assigned;
                    else
                        role.Assigned = false;
                    // Add the role to the list of potential roles of user.
                    user.Roles.Add(role);
                }
                // Add the user to user list.
                users.Add(user);
            }

            // Return list of users.
            return users;
        }
    }
```

And here is the view that is an htmp-page called index.html. I had created folder called Views in the project before I created this html-page. When Views folder had been created then I created this page inside this folder.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Users Directory</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Add" />
        <input type="button" value="Delete" />
        <input type="button" value="Save" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Users</h2>
        <table id="users" style="border: 1px solid black;"></table>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var uri = 'api/users';

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Send AJAX request.
            $.getJSON(uri)
                .done(function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                        $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#users'));
                    });
                });
        });

        function formatItem(item) {
            return item.Name;
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

But after the application starts the list of users is not shown in the application window. Why? Please help me correct this error.

Comment: Have you even tried to set a breakpoint in the API method to see if it's being called in the first place?

Comment: If I set breakpoint in controller method then the breakpoint is not activated.

Comment: That seems to indicate then that your API method isn't actually being called, I'd recommend investigating that first. Remember, http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/

Comment: I can't detected why API method is not called. Could anybody help me here?

Comment: It's been a while since I did any web development, try putting the first script tag inside the head tag, and then using the developer tools in something like Chrome, set a breakpoint in your document.ready function and see if that's being called.